# unable to delete subcategory with laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I know it sounds stupid but I've got strange issue with deleting my subcategories, when I try to delete my sub it gives me error that name and slug is required! seems I try to add input in database!

here is some images to make it clear for you:

[image]

[image]

Here is my controller destroy function:

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
      $subcategory = Subcategory::find($id);

      $subcategory->delete();

      Session::flash('success', 'Your Sub-Category Deleted successfully!');

      return redirect()->route('subcategories.index');
    }
```

And this is my form which you see in images above:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">

            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Subcategory Name</th>
                    <th>Slug</th>
                    <th>Parent Category</th>
                    <th>Operation</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              @foreach ($categories as $category)
              @foreach($category->subcategories as $sub)
              <tr>

                  <td>{{ $sub->id }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $sub->name }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $sub->slug }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $sub->category->name }}</td>
                  <td>
                    <a href="{{ URL::to('subcategories/'.$sub->id.'/edit') }}" class="btn-sm btn btn-info pull-left" style="margin-right: 3px;">Edit</a>
                    {!! Form::model(['route' => ['subcategories.destroy', $sub->id], 'method' => "DELETE"]) !!}
                      {{ Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-sm btn-danger']) }}
                    {!! Form::close() !!}
                  </td>

              </tr>
              @endforeach
              @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: Do you have any middleware for validating the form input that could've been added to the delete route by mistake?

Comment: show route details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it caused the `Form::open` return:

```
<form method="DELETE" action="{{route('subcategories.destroy', ['id' => $sub->id])}}">
```

I think that is the problem, I have same probleme here and I have read about this in [Laracast](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-can-i-delete-record-laravel-53).

So in my case I change not use `Form::open()`. I use manual form, and my code looked like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{route('subcategories.destroy', ['id' => $sub->id])}}">
    {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
.
.
.
</form>
```

I hope it can help you :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, also needs `<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">` and not this `{{ method_field('DELETE') }}`